# Is it possible to call a method from an object definition constructor function

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I have a constructor function in `JavaScript`, which I use to create my objects. How would I alter the "contents" of all the objects created by this function through a method call from this function. What I am wondering is, weather it is possible to invoke a method call upon the prototype, like we'd modify the prototype adding our own methods/properties.

For example:

```
function MyConstructor()
{
    var privateVariable = "This is an ORIGINAL private variable";
    this.publicVariable = "This is public";

    this.modificationMethod = function(){
    // I want to call this methode on the prototype
     privateVariable = "I am now changed";
    };

    this.alertMe = function(){
        alert(privateVariable);
    };
}

var a = new MyConstructor();
a.alertMe();        // alerts This is an ORIGINAL private variable
a.modificationMethod();
a.alertMe();        // alerts I am now changed
```

This works when I want to change a single object, I invoke the method, it changes that single object. However, I want to change all the objects that are created by the constructor.

I know I can add new methods to it like this:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.foo = function(){
    alert("foo");
}
a = new MyConstructor();
a.foo();
```

But it does not let me run the existing methods to change the properties, and throws an error:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.modificationMethod();
```

"modificationMethod is not a function"

Comment: `MyConstructor.prototype.foo = function(){this.modificationMethod()}; a = new MyConstructor(); a.foo()`

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue, it makes another method which will call the first method, but it never calls it. It just creates a method to call a method, whilst I need the method executed in order to change a private property for all the objects, the method must be invoked on the prototype, not an instance of one (`a`).

Comment: you are not able to get private properties from `prototype` cuz private properties exist only within `function constructor scope`

Comment: Once the function constructor scope is initialized, they start existing based on what their values were at the point of initialization. Which means, that the prototype has the values. A `new MyConstructor()` inherits the values of it's prototype for private properties so they DO exist on the prototype.

Comment: But within that same closure I should be able to invoke a method, to change the value of a variable. Even more to a point. NO method can be invoked from a prototype, at all, regardless of what it does. Point of private properties is moot, no method allows invocation on the prototype as it is not seen as a function. I would assume this is because there is no "this" in the prototype.

Comment: `this` references to currect object, inside prototype method. There is no way to get private data from proto, only via object method, as you have in constructor method

Comment: Make any constructor, within it, make any public method, then try to invoke it on the prototype object, it will throw an error. Is there a way around this? Is there any way to invoke a method on the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT**: Updating the answer to reflect everything discussed in comments. I initially misunderstood the OP's issue.*

---

Every object is linked to a prototype object. When trying to access a property that does not exist, JavaScript will look in the object's prototype object for that property and return it if it exists.

The prototype property of a function constructor refers to the prototype object of all instances created with that function when using new.

What that means is that prototype object is sort of a fallback mechanism when an object itself does not have the desired property.

---

The concept of private variables are in fact [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Prototype functions are defined outside of the constructor function scope, meaning they cannot access the "private properties".

However, it is possible to assign a closure to the prototype property itself, effectively making a private shared (static) variable.

```
function MyConstructor() {};

MyConstructor.prototype = (function() {

  var extensions = {
    foo: null,
    test: function() {
      alert("Test was extended");
    }
  };

  return {
    registerExtension: function(name, callback) {
      extensions[name] = callback;
    },
    // in order to use the extensions object, you need a generic function such as invoke
    invoke: function(name) {
      if (typeof extensions[name] === 'function')
        extensions[name].call(this);
    }
  };

}());

var a = new MyConstructor();
a.invoke('test');  //will alert
a.invoke('foo');   //will not alert (not a function)
a.registerExtension('foo', function() {
  alert("foo is now extended as well");
});
a.invoke('test');  //will alert
a.invoke('foo');   //will alert
```

---

A simpler approach, if you don't mind for the extended functions to be visible (public), would be to directly extend the `prototype`.

```
function MyConstructor() {};

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  foo: null,
  test: function() {
    alert("Test was extended");
  }
};

var a = new MyConstructor();
a.test();   //will alert
//a.foo();  //will not alert (not a function)
MyConstructor.prototype.foo = function() {
  alert("foo is now extended as well");
};
a = new MyConstructor();
a.test();  //will alert
a.foo();   //will alert
```

You can easily create an interface for prototype extension.

```
Object.prototype.registerExtension = function( name, func ){
    this.prototype[ name ] = func;
};

// ...

MyConstructor.registerExtension( 'foo', function() {
  alert("foo is now extended as well");
} );
```

Comment: I understand these concepts, however, you either worded it wrong or we do not have a clear understanding. To quote you `"If you wish to alter every instance, you have to call the functions individually"`. This would be true for existing instances, what I want to do is alter the prototype, and any future instance that uses this new, altered prototype would then gain different properties. I will elaborate further in the next reply.

Comment: From what I understand, and, correct me if I am wrong. When I create a `new` object this object gets created based on the **current state** of the prototype object of the constructor function. If the prototype object of the constructor function was to somehow change, all newly created instances would then have the new state. This is essentially what I am looking for. Now it is possible to do it by adding new properties which refer to functions to the prototype, all the objects will inherit it. But it seems impossible to invoke any method on the prototype as if the methods are not there at all.

Comment: Do you need to use private properties inside the prototype functions?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is since you already added the `foo` function to the prototype. Every object created with the `MyConstructor` function will look inside the `MyConstructor.prototype` object IF the desired property does not already exist within the object (instance) itself.

Comment: Pretty much, to elaborate as to clue you in a bit more on what is the actual purpose. I am making a sort of "library" or "framework", call it however you wish, which has certain objects, which have certain methods. In order to allow others to 'write extensions' for these methods without altering them, each object has a private property named "extenders". This property is an object (an empty one). Each object also has methods to "add" function callbacks to this object namely `addExtension('uniqueMethodID', callback);`

Comment: At the end of every method, within the object there is a `extenders['uniqueMethodID']();` and this virtually allows you to extend any method, after it has finished. There are some properties passed along but that is the idea

Comment: However, these sort of extensions have to happen (have to be registered) to a prototype, in order to avoid registering them for each individual object, behavior should remain the same across objects. And they would be extended during the `configuration` process, before any object is initialized. Sort of a 'framework extension'

Comment: I am truly sorry, but it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Could you supply a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The goal is to allow the users to "re-configure" and extend any of the methods they wish on the prototype, so that any object initialized after the changes were made to the prototype would get these changes.

**The only issue* in this entire thing is, I am unable to invoke a method on the prototype object, any method, regardless of what it is, does. `MyConstructor.prototype.<AnyMethodName>` always just returns "it is not a function"

Comment: Post the url here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ns73hogs/   Read comments before running. Weird last time i tried posting jsfiddle url it didnt work

Comment: *Every object is linked to a prototype object.* This is incorrect.

Comment: @torazaburo You are correct if you consider null to be an object.

Comment: @janje Wrong. `Object.create(null).__proto__` is `undefined`.

Comment: @torazaburo Exactly. null, by definition, has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain.

Comment: You're deeply confused about the difference between having a prototype, and not having one. The object created by `Object.create(null)` does not have a prototype of null; it has **no** prototype.

Comment: @torazaburo I am not sure if he is confused or not, but he is most certainly correct when it comes to answering the question I posted within his own context. I will now check if it holds water in my example.

Comment: @janje be with you in a sec, need to check if this works out actually for my case.

Comment: @torazaburo The recommended function `Object.getPrototypeOf(  Object.create(null) )` returns `null`.

Comment: @janje the methods you suggested work, with both of them having a limitation in that the extension MUST be defined before an object is instantised, but that was one of the premisses for the problem to begin with. If you have an idea of how to make it "backwards" compatible, would like to see it, but this as is, is a 100% correct answer! Thanks.

Comment: @Dellirium You can't define the `extensions` afterwards because that variable is defined within a closure of the prototype - which must be defined before any instance is created.

Comment: @Dellirium I updated the answer with the contents of the fiddle.

Comment: Yes I saw, very well done indeed. I know I cannot define extensions afterwards, what I meant is, and again this is just "bonus". Regardless of which method is chosen, only objects instantized after the prototype is modified will inherit the modifications, but again, this works fine for any serious system, you'd configure the whole system at start anyways

Comment: @Dellirium If you keep track of all the existing instances, you can easily add a property to each of them that refers to the newly added function. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spkgrzke/) out.

Comment: @janje I see, however I would not incorporate this into the system, simply because it "allows" for bad practice, and has a possibility of creating inconsistancies, generally speaking.

Comment: @Dellirium I agree. However, you could enforce it for all instances by making it automatic; that would at least be consistent. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfbd7b08/).

Comment: @janje True, but then I'd have to keep track of all the objects ever instantiated in a global so that it can be accessed through the interface.

Comment: @Dellirium You could hide that information in the same manner `extensions` were hidden in the first approach (making a closure when defining prototype). Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z64y77dj/) out!